# WatchKit table numberOfRows returns 0

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

I have simple table in my WatchKit test application with just a label per `TableRowController`. When I try to set the text for the labels, I can not loop through the rows of the table view because `table.numberOfRows` returns 0.

However calling `[self.table setNumberOfRows:x withRowType:@"RowController"];` the number of rows gets set to whatever number x is. This confirms that the IB reference to self.table is working.

What could be the problem?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    // Configure interface objects here.

    [self configureTableWithData];
}

- (void)willActivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user

    [super willActivate];
}

- (void)didDeactivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    [super didDeactivate];
}

- (void)configureTableWithData {
    [self.table setNumberOfRows:1 withRowType:@"RowController"];
    NSLog(@"%i",self.table.numberOfRows);
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.table.numberOfRows; i++) {
        TableRowController* theRow = [self.table rowControllerAtIndex:i];
        [theRow.timeLabel setText:@"Hello!"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was actually quite simple, but very hard to track down. It turns out that my `TableRowController` class was not target member of my WatchKit Extension, only my main app.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you have also to check if the module is valid for current WatchKit extension.